# Run time error 1004 on add-in: file could not be sabed because it is read only

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, add-in

Sometimes when I open Excel I got a run time 1004 error message. Prompting that my add-in (xlam) file could not be saved because it is read only. That is annoying because I never know when its is going to happen and what is causing the problem.

This is the piece of code executed when the add-in is open:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'I initialize some variables
configurado = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro").Range("a1")
proxyObrigatorio = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro").Range("a2")
ipProxy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro").Range("a3")
portaProxy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro").Range("a4")  

'I insert the xlam's name in the G1 range and save the xlam file
fileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculos").Range("G1") = fileName    

End Sub
```

What could be possible causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening an excel file. Instead of opening another one using an existing excel file, go to start menu -> excel, and open from there. Does that cause the error? If it does then it is because you are opening a second "read only" session of excel.

If you open one excel file and want to open another, be sure to open the next excel file you want to use by way of File->Open in the first excel file. That way you are using multiple files in one session, rather then starting another excel session. Sorry if this sounds a bit confusing, its early, and Monday but let me know if this works.

If you have to open multiple excel files with two different sessions, then you are going to have to save your macro in a different place. Essentially the first file is accessing your macro workbook and is in "edit" mode with it. When opening the second file, it finds the first already accessing the workbook and can only do a read only version.